# Delete duplicate rows without considering primary key

Tags: sql, sqlite, distinct

I'm trying to remove duplicates from my table. The problem is that each row has different Primary Key so it seems like there no duplicates.

I've decided to create a temporary table and fill it with DISTINCT rows without pk's.

SQLite3 says that there is a syntax error. Do you know where is the problem?

EDIT: The problem is obviously that I'm trying to insert multiple rows in one INSERT. How to modify the query to work on all rows?

```
INSERT INTO records_temp 
            (title, 
             image, 
             stav, 
             product_url, 
             vyrobca, 
             objednacie_cislo, 
             katalogove_cislo, 
             popis, 
             parametre, 
             mnozstvo, 
             kus_bez_dph, 
             kus_s_dph, 
             celkom_s_dph, 
             url_kategoria, 
             category) 
VALUES      (SELECT DISTINCT title, 
                             image, 
                             stav, 
                             product_url, 
                             vyrobca, 
                             objednacie_cislo, 
                             katalogove_cislo, 
                             popis, 
                             parametre, 
                             mnozstvo, 
                             kus_bez_dph, 
                             kus_s_dph, 
                             celkom_s_dph, 
                             url_kategoria, 
                             category 
             FROM   records)
```

Comment: insert into t1 (c1, c2,... ) select ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `VALUES` keyword is not needed for `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO records_temp 
        (title, 
         image, 
         stav, 
         product_url, 
         vyrobca, 
         objednacie_cislo, 
         katalogove_cislo, 
         popis, 
         parametre, 
         mnozstvo, 
         kus_bez_dph, 
         kus_s_dph, 
         celkom_s_dph, 
         url_kategoria, 
         category) 
    SELECT DISTINCT title, 
                         image, 
                         stav, 
                         product_url, 
                         vyrobca, 
                         objednacie_cislo, 
                         katalogove_cislo, 
                         popis, 
                         parametre, 
                         mnozstvo, 
                         kus_bez_dph, 
                         kus_s_dph, 
                         celkom_s_dph, 
                         url_kategoria, 
                         category 
         FROM   records
```